# adding number to foreach loop php

Tags: php

I created a small script which is getting some results from a json file

```
foreach ($obj as $key) {
    echo "encoder: ".($obj_info->customname)."\n";
    $naam = ($key->Name);
    echo "ChannelName: ". $naam." "."\n";
    if (isset($naam)) {
        foreach ($key->Device->Template->Tracks->AudioTracks as $audiotrack) {
            echo "AUDIO PID: ".$audiotrack->Pid."\n";
            echo "Codec:     ".$audiotrack->Encoding->Codec."\n";
        }
```

This gives then the result:

```
ChannelName: Channel X
AUDIO PID: 0
Codec:     MPEG AAC
AUDIO PID: 0
Codec:     MPEG AAC
AUDIO PID: 0
Codec:     MPEG AAC
```

Because the audio pid  result is an unknown factor i have this foreach loop created but there i would like to add based on the result a number to the audio pid

```
AUDIO PID 1: 0
Codec
AUDIO PID 2: 0
Codec
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: you could use a counter... `$counter++` on each loop and concatenate it to `"AUDIO PID " . $counter . ":" `

Answer (score 3):

Well, as simple as it is, you can use a variable that you increment on each iteration :

```
if (isset($naam)) {

    $pidNumber = 1; // <-------------

    foreach ($key->Device->Template->Tracks->AudioTracks as $audiotrack) {
        // -----------------v----------v
        echo "AUDIO PID " . $pidNumber++ . " : " . $audiotrack->Pid."\n";
        echo "Codec:     ".$audiotrack->Encoding->Codec."\n";
    }
```

Comment: Correct answer, so +1 from me,  but it would probably be clearer to the OP if you incremented `$pidNumber` on a separate line.